# Open custom data file from internal assets folder (LibGDX)

Tags: java, file, libgdx, assets

I have created a custom made file that loads up a spritesheet into my game. The problem is that I cannot access this file. The file is in the assets folder where all other files such as Textures are stored. I tried this:

`Gdx.files.internal("images/tiles/defaulttileset/init.tileset").file()`

I am trying to get a `java.io.File`, not a LibGDX `FileHandle`, since I am loading the files data using the `java.utils.Scanner` class.

Currently, when I try to load it, the game crashes once it reaches the scanner constructor where the file is passed since the file is considered to be non-existent.

**More info:** When I use the `file.getPath()` method, it returns "images/tiles/defaulttileset/init.tileset". It seems that it is trying to access that file on the computer's hard drive rather than the game's assets folder.

Does anyone have a solution?

Comment: Why do you have to use java.io.File or java.utils.Scanner at all?

Comment: It seems like it is returning a matching file path? Have you done a Refresh All with Gradle since moving the file into the project?

Comment: No I haven't, how do you do this? Also grimradar22, I am using them because it's what I know how to use and has most versatility for me.

Comment: Edit: I figured out how to refresh, it did not solve my problem.

Comment: See the javadocs for the `file()` method. It's not usable for internal files. I think this is because the "internal" directory is a resource directory, but I'm not an expert of file management in Java. You can get an InputStream via the `read()` method instead.

Comment: Ah yes thank you Tenfour04 it worked. Thanks everyone!